# Ng build --watch produces invalid sourcemaps

Tags: angular, angular-cli

I am not sure why, but since Angular 8, the `ng build` started working weird.

Firstly `ng build --watch` stopped producing valid source maps (they are generated, but not recognised by the browser). I found out that that would get solved by adding `--source-map` option.

Within a few weeks, the `ng build --watch --source-maps` and I am not sure how to solve it. I can do `ng build` that produces valid (browser readable) source maps, but it is so much slower...

Does anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had enabled Chrome's `fileSystem` integration in sources panel. For some reason that did break it.